# How do i figure out the maker of my bike?

Tags: frames, bmx

There are no words on it, it is a chrome frame and the only markings i found on it were a serial number that reads G1109025563. Is there any way i can get any information on it?

Comment: In a word, "no".

Comment: If you post a photo of it there's some chance that someone here will recognise it. But I can't imagine the sort of person who would memorise serial numbers.

Comment: Serial numbers aren't very useful in bicycle identification. Photos help a lot more, especially close ups of any logos, designs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

90% chance its a generic BSO.  If you have a distinct feature, post a photo and someone might recognise it, but...

Why do you want to bother identifying the maker?  You already have a frame that will have certain dimensions or bearing sizes.  There's little if anything to be gained from buying parts from the manufacturer.

Your best tools are likely to be a vernier caliper and a thread gauge, to find specs for parts you might need to make frame into a whole bike.